# What is the origin of this coin? Willem WRL

Tags: identification, numismatics

My great-grandfather saved a bunch of very old coins from all around the world and from different times just for me, 7 years after he died, the coins were given to me. Here is one that I cannot find anywhere and don't know what it is. Could anyone please help!

Obverse:

[image: Obverse]

Reverse:

[image: Reverse]

Answer (score 25):

From the portrait, it looks to be a William I (William the Conqueror) "bonnet-type" silver penny.

[image: William I bonnet-type silver penny]

However, you should also be aware that there are a lot of replica and [reproduction](http://dorchesters.com/william-i-the-conqueror-penny-bonnet-type) issues of that particular coin.

---

As noted by @SimonB and @richardb in the comments, your coin appears to have the letters '*WR*L' stamped on the obverse, which indicates that it is a replica produced by [Westair Reproductions Ltd](http://www.westair-reproductions.com/).

This replica is currently available to purchase as the [Battle of Hastings Coin Pack - William I](http://www.westair-reproductions.com/Medieval/Battle+of+Hastings+Coin+Pack+-+William+I.html).

Comment: @MarcSharko and some of the people who make reproductions helpfully stamp their initials on the coin, so you know it's a reproduction.  Yours is stamped "WRL".

Comment: @SimonB Westair Reproductions Ltd [http://www.westair-reproductions.com/]

Comment: Just a note; the page you link to says that the inscription on the obverse is "+PILLEMUS REX". That is more likely to be a _[wynn](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wynn)_ (Ƿ) than an actual P. Ƿ is pronounced like a "w" , so ǷILLEMUS is "Willemus".